# `Trying to get property of non-object` using `hasManyThrough` relationship laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, has-many-through

I am trying to develop a blog using `Laravel 5` in which i have to show comment along with user on post.

Here is my database table schema.

`User`

- id
- name

`Posts`

- id
- post_content
- user_id

`Comments`

- id
- comment
- user_id
- post_id

Here is my `User Model`

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Posts');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Comments','App\Models\Posts');
}
```

Here is my `Posts Model`

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('Ap\Models\Comments');
    }
```

Here is my `Comment Model`

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Posts');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->posts->name;
    }
```

Here is my code how i am accessing `user name`

```
$comments = Comments::find(1);
$comment['comment'] = $comments->comment;
$comment['user_name'] = $comments->name;
$comment['post_id'] = $comments->posts->id;
```

may be i am not getting in right direction? if i am doing right then why it is not working.

Comment: are your models in the App\Model namespace? default is just App...

Comment: @Gregory yes my models are in App\Models namespace, I have just modified little bit.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 you do not call the model as you are doing. since the models are stored in the app folder just call like. Plus I think you need to define the relationship

```
class User extends Model {

    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }

}

class Phone extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}

$phone = Phone::find(1);
```

For the case of foreign keys and more regarding the Eloquent relationships in laravel 5 just follow the documentation on the laravel website. Make sure to look at dynamic properties of that are allowed by eloquent

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent